# edittext visibility change at runtime depending upon it's visibility

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello all i want to do

1]if **edittext** is ***visible*** then ***invisible*** and if ***invisible*** then ***visible*** to it for that i have done this

```
 btn_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // fragment=new BBQ();
                    // Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    // Search_Activity.class);
                    // startActivity(i);

                    ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


                    if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.INVISIBLE)
                    {
                        ed.setVisibility(arg0.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        ed.setVisibility(arg0.INVISIBLE);
                    }
    }
```

for me if it if invisible then it make visible but on second click it not invisible what is wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll say that you should else-if condition:

```
if(ed.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)  {
   ed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if(ed.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)  {
    ed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Or with the ternary operator:

```
 ed.setVisibility (ed.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE ?  View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code

```
if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.INVISIBLE)
{
 ed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.VISIBLE)
{
 ed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

`}`

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

May be when the code enters the first if, later you modify the visibility and set again invisible, so it enters again in  the second if, try this:

```
if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.INVISIBLE)
{
    ed.setVisibility(arg0.VISIBLE);
} 
else if(ed.getVisibility()==arg0.VISIBLE)
{
    ed.setVisibility(arg0.INVISIBLE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

EditText having `tag` attribute initility set the tag as **visible** then while giving **invisible** `setTag("invisible");` or `setTag("visible");`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/url_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="visible" />
```

**Code**

```
if(ed.getTag().equals("visible"))
{
         ed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         ed.setTag("invisible");
}
else if(ed.getTag().equals("invisible"))
{
         ed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         ed.setTag("visible");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Boolean isVisible=true;
ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
btn_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   if(isVisible){
             ed.setVisibility(arg0.INVISIBLE);
                  }else{
  ed.setVisibility(arg0.VISIBLE);
}
isVisible=!isVisible;

}
```